# What IAM roles/permissions do I need to enable an API on someone else's GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-solar-api

Someone at my organisation created a Google Cloud Project and granted me access. I want to enable the Solar API and generate an API key for it.

Is there any IAM role they can give me so that I can do this myself? It seems to me that this should be a basic question, but I cannot find a straight answer anywhere.

I already have the roles Admin, API Keys Admin, ApiGateway Admin, Maps API Admin and Service Consumer. However, when I try to enable the Solar API, the website gives me an "Insufficient permissions to check the enablement status of this product" error.

Comment: Look into service usage admin role or permission : serviceusage.services.enable. Menu > IAM & admin > roles > filter by serviceusage.services.enable (will give you all roles containing that particular permission)

Comment: @danyL Thanks, that seems to have worked. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: The `solar` API is part of Google Maps. That means you will also need to setup Google Maps Platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by `dany L` you need to have permission : **serviceusage.services.enable**. These APIs are core GCP components and require special permissions. The roles which you have enabled as of now are only useful for managing the resources. If you need to enable any core GCP APIs you need to have the **Service Usage Admin role**   this [official document](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control#:%7E:text=roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin) lists all the permissions available for this role.